Errors when trying to submit offline conversions via CONVERSIONS_API
I'm getting Error 500 Internal Server Error when testing on POST requests, in order to send offline conversions through API.
The payload is one of the examples I found in Linkedin's API documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/conversions-api?view=li-lms-2024-04&tabs=http#streaming-conversion-events
Here's the payload I used
    {
      "conversion": "urn:lla:llaPartnerConversion:17327729",
      "conversionHappenedAt": 1713533960658,
      "conversionValue": {
           "currencyCode": "BRL",
           "amount": "1"
       },
       "user": {
           "userIds":  {
               "idType": "SHA256_EMAIL",
               "idValue": "c1bc7a0cacf53e2e55287e17d3ab606335d59e83f80c0bbea5ec26489d8fa5fd"
               },
          "userInfo": {
                   "firstName": "Teste",
                "lastName": "Teste",
                "title": "teste",
                "companyName": "teste",
                "countryCode": "US"
             }
         },
    "eventId" : "teste123"
}

And here's the code postman generated from the attempt:
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/conversionEvents"

payload = json.dumps({
  "conversion": "urn:lla:llaPartnerConversion:17327729",
  "conversionHappenedAt": 1713533960658,
  "conversionValue": {
    "currencyCode": "BRL",
    "amount": "1"
  },
  "user": {
    "userIds": {
      "idType": "SHA256_EMAIL",
      "idValue": "c1bc7a0cacf53e2e55287e17d3ab606335d59e83f80c0bbea5ec26489d8fa5fd"
    },
    "userInfo": {
      "firstName": "Teste",
      "lastName": "Teste",
      "title": "teste",
      "companyName": "teste",
      "countryCode": "US"
    }
  },
  "eventId": "teste123"
})
headers = {
  'Linkedin-Version': '202404',
  'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxx',
      'Cookie': 'lidc="b=VB65:s=V:r=V:a=V:p=V:g=4764:u=5:x=1:i=1713556280:t=1713629224:v=2:sig=AQHE02OY-X8M13nqna7qIRNZzFOuEHwz"; bcookie="v=2&f6bb8698-d25f-4655-8581-4edc1a0b2a6f"'
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

I'm getting all sorts of errors, but this is the most annoying one 'cause it's not clear what's wrong and where it's wrong.
Thanks in advance for the assistance with this.
